# Android: arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is not working with sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am trying to update the ListView after deleting the row. I tried many ways but its not working.I want to delete a row by clicking on that and then update the listview.

here is my code:

```
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            delID = position+1;
            //openAlert(v);
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete");
             alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure want to delete?");
             // set positive button: Yes message

                      alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {




                                        mydb.deleteContact(delID);

                                       arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                             }

                           });
```

Please help me i am fade up from this.

Comment: Could you please try `arrayAdapter.clear();` before using `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`?

Comment: What i meant was `arrayAdapter.clear();` and then adding your contacts again may be using `arrayAdapter.addAll()`before using `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: add again means??how can?

Comment: It works by simply adding clear()..I was trying last 4 hours.Thanks a lot

Comment: That's great.Glad that your late night hard work finally gave you some relief. :P Also i should have added my comment as an answer then. :D